# batch trim wav files using sox

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to batch trim audio files (wav) using sox, trimming first 15 seconds

When I run the following on a single file, it works, by creating a file 'snipped.wav' minus first 15 seconds, in the same folder

```
@echo off
cd E:\trim\singlefile
sox original.wav snipped.wav trim 15
```

However, when I try the following on multiple files (with processed files after trim should move to 'trimmed' folder), it does not work:

```
@echo off
cd E:\trim\multiplefiles
mkdir trimmed
FOR %%A IN (%*) DO sox "%%A" "trimmed/%%~nA" trim 15
```

I guess I am (awfully) wrong somewhere. Please suggest.

Comment: Use just `*` instead of `%*` and use ``\`` instead of `/` in path. Run in a command prompt window `call /?` to get explained what `%*` means and run in same command prompt window `for /?` to get help on this command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the for-loop on a wrong way. You have to provide the files you want to iterate through between the parenthesis. `%*` actually means "all arguments". You need something like `*.wav` (which means all files in the current folder ending with ".wav") or `*` (meaning all files in current folder).
You also may want to use `%%~A` inside your double quotes too. It will remove surrounding double quotes if they already were present in `%%A`, else you may have double pairs of double quotes (for eg `""this should be one string""`) and the effect of the double quotes will be undone. And are you sure about the `"trimmed\%%~nA"` part? With the `~n` you're leaving out the extension of the filename (if `%%A` would be `original.wav`, `%%~nA` will become `original`). Use `~nx` if you want filename and the extension at the end (see link at the end).
Here is the loop you should have:

```
FOR %%A IN (*.wav) DO sox "%%~A" "trimmed\%%~nA" trim 15
```

if you do want to have the extension in the `"trimmed\%%~nA"` part, replace it with `"trimmed\%%~nxA"`

[This link](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html) talks about the different for-loops in batch.
[This link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ben/2007/03/09/path-manipulation-in-a-batch-file/) talks about the different path manipulation techniques you can use on arguments and loop-variables

Comment: thanks for reply. tried all the above, but not working ( does not create snipped file in 'trimmed' folder )

Comment: k, this is what I did:

Comment: @echo off
cd E:\trim\multiplefiles
mkdir trimmed
FOR /F %%A IN ("*.wav") DO sox "%%A" "trimmed\%%~nxA" trim 15

Comment: I placed 3 files x.wav, y.wav, and z.wav in the folder. On running the batch file, it merged all 3 wav files into one file named "x.wav" in the 'trimmed' folder. The individual file lengths were 0:01:17, 0:02:08, and 0:02:42 respectively (summing up to 00:06:07). The merged file was (00:05:53) , so minus 14 seconds. So, how to have individual trimmed files in 'trimmed' folder, and each trimmed by 15 seconds ?

Comment: My appologies I thought you were giving all your files as arguments to the batch-file because of the `%*` you used in your post. That's why I proposed the `FOR /F` with the `%*`.  I reacted too quick

Comment: So you want to iterate through all files in the `E:\trim` directory?

Comment: I changed my answer, I was confused at the beginning because of the `%*`  you used in your post. So you were using the correct for-loop  but with the wrong loop-elements (`%*` instead of `*.wav`). My sincere apologies for the inconvenience

Comment: thanks, could the correct code be suggested for batch process ?

Comment: Yes it would work. If you replace your for-loop in the second code sample of in question with the for-loop in my answer it will work. If you want to use a `FOR` loop in the command-line you'll have to use loop-variables with single `%` instead of `%%` (so you would use `%A` instead of `%%A` for a for-loop on the command line)

Comment: Again, my appologies for the inconvenience caused by my missunderstanding

Comment: can you replace this code with the one you are suggesting.                       FOR /F %%A IN ("*.wav") DO sox "%%A" "trimmed\%%~nxA" trim 15                               - You see, I am not exactly an expert at Batch.  Thank you , in anticipation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129107/discussion-between-j-baoby-and-vicki).